# Converting decimal to base58check using Python 3.7

Tags: python, base58

As part of the routine I have used

```
ALPHABET = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz"

def convertToBase58(num):
    sb = ''

    while (num > 0):
        r = num % 58   # divide by 58 and gives the remainder
        sb = sb + ALPHABET[r]
        num = num / 58;
    return sb[::-1]
```

This comes back with an error saying that r has to be an integer. But using the % operator seems to define r as integer. What have I missed, please ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a generic Python programming question that belongs on another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: OK I accept this. I do not know Python as well as I should. BUT, there seems to be no dedicated Python Stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

The `r` variable has not been defined as an integer. However, the `num` variable as been defined as a `float` on the second iteration of the loop. It's a result of the last line in the loop `num = num / 58`.

The division operator returns a float.  In Python 3.5+ use `//` to return an integer.

Older versions of Python can use `math.floor`